Detect proxy authentication
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient()) {                
            string baseurl = settings.BaseUrl;
            string url = $"{baseurl}api/V1/{controller}/{action}";                
            using HttpRequestMessage message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);                
            message.Headers.Add("authorization", "Bearer " + settings.AuthTokenString);

            using HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(message);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
                string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return result;
            } else {
                _ = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                //If we did not recieve a success
                throw new HttpRequestException(response.StatusCode + "");                    
            }
        }

I am using the code above, to call an api. This works as expected, but if I enable "Require Proxy Authentication" in Fiddler, the client.SendAsync call throws an exception, instead of returning a response with a 407 status code.
Is there a nicer way to detect proxy authentication, than catching this exception an searching the message for "407"?

Probably you can find existing issues on GitHub dotnet/runtime repo.
